# mongodb folder absolute path in package.json error at 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, package.json

Have in my package.json some scripts as follow:

```
"start-admin-endpoints": "concurrently \"npm run mongo-start-admin-without-system-variable\" wait-on \"nodemon server.js\"",
"mongo-start-admin": " mongod --port 27017 --auth --storageEngine=wiredTiger --journal --dbpath=\"C:/data/db\"",
"mongo-start-admin-without-system-variable": " \"%ProgramFiles%/MongoDB/Server/4.2/bin/mongod\" --port 27017 --auth --storageEngine=wiredTiger --journal --dbpath=\"C:/data/db\"",
```

where its called by command: `npm run start-admin-endpoints` that originates the following error:

```
[0] >  "%ProgramFiles%/MongoDB/Server/4.2/bin/mongod" --port 27017 --auth --storageEngine=wiredTiger --journal --dbpath="C:/data/db"
[0]
[0] 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[0] operable program or batch file.
[0] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[0] npm ERR! errno 1
```

since already using %ProgramFiles% the windows alternative name to avoid the the space for the Program Files folder and the double quotes don't get why its still giving this error and how to fix (testing in windows 7).

Have it working in a windows 10 when the script `"start-admin-endpoints": "concurrently \"npm run mongo-start-admin\" wait-on \"nodemon server.js\""`, means that created in `windows environment - system variables - path` Have defined the path for mongodb as follow: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\`
and its working well, but wanted also be able to use the absolute path in script in case of not having access to environment variables of windows.

Comment: if your windows 7 is 32bit you will need to use `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` instead of `%ProgramFiles%`

Comment: nope it keeps giving the error and had already confirmed that the folder is in this path